# What can I do with a super combinator or combinator?

Tags: haskell

I am reading on the page https://wiki.haskell.org/Super_combinator and would like to know, what is the purpose of the super combinator?

And I would like to understand the following context:

> Any lambda expression is of the form \x1 x2 .. xn -> E, where E is not
>   a lambda abstraction and n≥0. (Note that if the expression is not a
>   lambda abstraction, n=0.) This is a supercombinator if and only if:
>
> - the only free variables in E are x1..xn, and
> - every lambda abstraction in E is a supercombinator.

the first point confuses me, because

```
\x y -> x + y
```

`x` and `y` are bound variables and therefore they are not free.

Comment: Is your question the one you asked in the title, or why x and y are considered free variables?

Comment: As to the purpose, I think it's already in the page you linked: *"Because supercombinators have no free variables, they can always be given their own names and let floated to the top level"*

Comment: @RobertHarvey the second question is, why `x` and `y` are considered as free variables?

Comment: The first point only applies if there *are* free variables in `E`. If there aren't any, then it is vacuously true that all free variables in `E` are one of the parameters.

Comment: `x` and `y` are not free in the expression `\x y -> x + y`. But `x` and `y` *are* free in the expression `x + y`.